# NSum not able to sum Abs[Sin[n]]

Tags: numerics, summation

Is it a bug?

```
In[1]:= NSum[Abs[Sin[n]], {n, 1, 24}]
Out[1]= 15.7476
In[2]:= NSum[Abs[Sin[n]], {n, 1, 25}]
NSum::nsnum: Summand (or its derivative) Cos[n] (Abs^\[Prime])[Sin[n]] is not numerical at point n = 16.
Out[2]= NSum[Abs[Sin[n]], {n, 1, 25}]
```

Version: 11.2.0.0

OS: Windows 10 (64-bit)

Comment: Seems to happen here too... 11.2 on OSX. As a workaround: `Total[Abs[Sin[#]] & /@ Range[25]] // N` seems to work fine. So bug is in NSum and not in Sin[ ].

Comment: on 11.1 windows 10  too

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. `NSum` uses extrapolation to approximate the result. This approximation requires taking derivatives of the input. Your input does not have a derivative defined over the complex plane, and so Mathematica issues an error message and returns the input unevaluated.

Comment: Same on 10.4 Win10. (`N@Sum[...]` works fine, though).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default [`NSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSum.html) uses 15 terms at the beginning before approximating the tail. The approximation tries to take the derivative of `Abs` which is undefined. You can avoid the issue by using the option `NSumTerms`

```
NSum[Abs[Sin[n]], {n, 1, 25}, NSumTerms -> 25]

(* 15.8799 *)
```

Comparing with

```
N@Total@Abs@Sin@Range[25]

(* 15.8799 *)
```

Comment: It's strange that NSum[RealAbs[Sin[n]], {n, 1, 25}] outputs 16.081.